# How to use Sharepoint Online to authourize access to remote site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, iis, custom-web-app

We have a website that runs on our local server which has a publicly available domain.  This site has a sql server data source and pages to work with the data.  This site needs to require a login to access it.

Now, all the users that will use this site also have an account in our 365 online, and I don't want to issue a separate username and password for my local site.

Is there a way to make my own webapp use Sharepoint's authentication so users wouldn't need two logins?

I'm looking at [this page from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to add `microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.microsoftaccount`. Am I right to think this will let me use the authentication in my own webform app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is create an app registration in Azure Active Directory and sign your users in using that.

There are a bunch of tutorials/samples on the web (like [this one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg)) but they're more aligned with .Net Core/MVC. If you're running WebForms you might some additional sleuthing to do.

Comment: Hmmm...  I've not worked with MVC yet.  Not really wanting to learn something else.

Comment: Would you choose Razor or MVC? Both are asp.net core, no?

Comment: Yeah. There's more content on the web for MVC so if you don't want to have to figure a bunch of stuff out, it's probably the way to go.  On the other hand, Razor is more similar to web forms in that you have a sort of "code-behind" pattern although it's not quite the same.

Comment: Sorry, one more question and I'm getting off-topic (and I'm reading up on these topics); the solution you linked - it says MVC, but isn't Razor MVC, too?  I'm suspecting I can't use Razor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121928/asp-net-core-razor-pages-vs-full-mvc-core

Comment: wow, I wish I could ask you a bunch of other questions.  I need a little guidance.